# FAQ: What kind of questions should I not ask here?

Tags: discussion

I was looking through the FAQ and noticed the following line under the heading of "[What kind of questions should I not ask here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)".

> You should only ask **practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face**.

While this is fine for most sites, I think it encourages the wrong sort of questions for this site. If the question is about a problem you face (rather than requesting a review of your solution to that problem) then it is off topic. Actually the first two paragraphs in that section could use some attention.

I'm not entirely confident with my wording and so will propose it as an answer, that way others may propose alternatives and vote appropriately.

Comment: It's a pity we don't have an appropriate tag for questions regarding the FAQ. I thought about creating one but couldn't come up with a good name as "FAQ" is already taken by something with a very different and specific meaning :)

Comment: This is a very good point, but sadly that section of the FAQ is not editable (at least not by mere moderators).

Answer (score 5):

> You should only ask for reviews of code that you are actually working on and is (to your knowledge) already functioning correctly. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If the specific code you wish to have reviewed will not fit in the question, you’re asking too much.